# How to make an overlay using css hover on another element and pseudo class ::before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Problem: The overlay must be displayed when the circle is hovered. I am trying to do this with css. I know how to do it when the image is hovered, and then the image gets the overlay, but how to display this overlay for the image when the circle is hovered? Below in my css i have left comments of my code for clarity. For me would be good even an explanation and example with javascript or jQuery how to archive this result.

HTML:

```
<div class="caption">
    <span class="point"></span>
    <img src="http://www.blasdale.com/pictures/2007/Hendon/thumbs/IMG_3337.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.caption {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}

.caption::before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: background .35s ease-out;
}
/* This block of code is working. When i hover on my img, it gets the overlay
.caption:hover::before {
    background: rgba(248, 214, 215, .5);
}
*/

/* I want that when i hover on the circle, the image would get this overlay, but this doesn't work */
.point:hover: + .caption::before {
    background: rgba(248, 214, 215, .5);
}

.point {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0qgcn2uu/

Comment: Not sure that parent selection is possible in CSS: https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/ ?

Comment: I think you're doing it backwards. You're trying to modify a parent element on a change made to one of its children elements.

What is it exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pure CSS Solution *No jQuery or JavaScript***

Selecting a **parent** tag is not possible, even in CSS 3.

As asked, yes, it is possible by moving the `.point` outside. Have a look here:

```
<span class="point"></span>
<div class="caption">
    <img src="http://www.blasdale.com/pictures/2007/Hendon/thumbs/IMG_3337.jpg" />
</div>
```

**Working Snippet**

```css
.caption {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}

.caption::before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  transition: background .35s ease-out;
}
/* This block of code is working. When i hover on my img, it gets the overlay
.caption:hover::before {
background: rgba(248, 214, 215, .5);
}
*/

/* I want that when i hover on the circle, the image would get this overlay, but this doesn't work */
.point:hover + .caption::before {
  background: rgba(248, 214, 215, .5);
}

.point {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<span class="point"></span>
<div class="caption">
  <img src="http://www.blasdale.com/pictures/2007/Hendon/thumbs/IMG_3337.jpg" />
</div>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0qgcn2uu/3/**

**Note:** Only issue with this is, make sure you enclose both the `.point` and `.caption` and its contents inside something with a `position: relative`, if you are using multiple instances.

Comment: Than you for the answer and explanation! it really helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".point").mouseover(function() {
      $('.caption').addClass('captionHover'); 
   });

   $('.point').mouseleave(function() {
       $('.caption').removeClass('captionHover'); 
   });
});
```

CSS:

```
.captionHover::before {
    background: rgba(248, 214, 215, .5);
}
```

[Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/0qgcn2uu/2/)

Comment: *The overlay must be displayed when the circle is hovered. I am trying to do this with css.*

Comment: Yes, but i have edited after it my answer for an javascript or jQuery solution, sorry for the delay..

Comment: I was reading what he explicitly wrote on the question: "I am trying to do this with css". I don't know why there are JS / jQuery tags here, as they are not needed...

Comment: Than you for the js solution! Daniel Kmak